# Android record multiple audio at a time?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I need to record more than one audio at a time. I have two record buttons if I clicked the first record button audio recording will be started. Before stop that audio recording If I am clicking the second record button I need to record the another one audio separately. Is there possibility to record more than one audio at a time ?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible, unless you have multiple Microphones.

The Reason behind this answer is, Recording is an `synchronized` method, so only one instance can use it at a time.

Comment: I think many Android phones have a `CAMCORDER` microphone locating near camera and a `MIC` microphone at the bottom. I tried to record them at the same time. And you are right, it doesn't work.