# On Android, is it possible to record multiple audio files at the same time?

Tags: android, android-studio

On Android, is there a way to record multiple audio files at the same time?  The recording would be from the same source (standard mic) but the starting of recording times would differ.

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715505/android-record-multiple-audio-at-a-time?rq=1). The answer is no, unless you have multiple microphones. Perhaps work with copies of one file instead and trim them according to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using mutiple threads...
I hope you know how to do that :-P
Or just record to one file, edit that, so the beginning is later, and copy it to somewhere else